# find and get next Elements with same calss with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

i have several span tags with same classes (.blue)
and several span tags with same classes (.black)
these tags will created via clicking  .
and i have a counter box for finding out the length .

my code :

```
<button id="btn">click me!</button>
<button id="btn2">click me!</button>
<div id="div1" style="background-color: #00f2f2;width: 1000px">
    <input id="inp" value="0">
    say hi
</div>
<script>
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        var span1 = $('<span />').addClass('blue');
        $("#div1").append(span1);
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function () {
        var span2 = $('<span />').addClass('black');
        $("#div1").append(span2);
    })
```

as you know the spans tags will created at source ,
and we can see them there ,
and if we click btn and btn2 by random , the source is :

```
<span class="blue"></span>
<span class="black"></span>
<span class="black"></span>
<span class="black"></span>
<span class="blue"></span>
<span class="blue"></span>
```

now my question is here
how can i sort these ?
for Example :
after 3 (.black) do anything ...
like that ,

```
<span class="black"></span>
<span class="black"></span>
<span class="black"></span>
```

now do ....

i want a condition to handle all child - note - element

last Example :

```
true :                                       false : 
<span class="blue"></span>                     <span class="blue"></span>
<span class="black"></span>                    <span class="blue"></span>
<span class="black"></span>                    <span class="blue"></span>
<span class="black"></span>                    <span class="black"></span>   
<span class="blue"></span>
```

how to handle and sort next - before and all nods with same classes ?

i hope you understand my issue

Comment: Please can you elaborate more not sure what you need to actually achieve.

Comment: for example : if first span is .black and 2nd is .blue . check to find 3 .black classes near

Comment: how to have a condition to check 
is .black ?
is .black ?

Comment: and when find 3 .black  classes . put them in a variable

Comment: so black should be  in a `group of 3`  and when blue span will append it will go anywhere  but not inside that group of 3 ?

Comment: yes i want to have a condition who find 3 or (x) number of same classes that are near in source , 
1 . black 
2 . blue 
3.  black 
4 . black 
5 . black 

look here from number 3 to number 5 is the target ,

Answer (score 1):

Tell me if its what you are looking for

```js
$("#btn").click(function () {
    var span1 = $('<span />').addClass('blue');
    $("#div1").append(span1);
    $('.countBlue').text(countSpan('blue'));
    countCheck('black', 'blue');
});
$("#btn2").click(function () {
    var span2 = $('<span />').addClass('black');
    $("#div1").append(span2);
    $('.countBlack').text(countSpan('black'));
    countCheck('black', 'blue');
});

function countSpan(classSpan) {
  var countItems = $('.' + classSpan).length;
  if (countItems >= 3) {
    console.log("count " + classSpan + " is egal to " + countItems);
    // do something
  }
 
  var numItems = "Number of elements with class " + classSpan + " is : " + countItems;
  return numItems;
}

function countCheck(classSpan1, classSpan2) {
  var countItems1 = $('.' + classSpan1).length, countItems2 = $('.' + classSpan2).length;
  if (countItems1 == 3 && countItems2 == 2) {
    console.log(classSpan1 + ' is egal to ' + countItems1 + ' and ' + classSpan2 + ' is egal to ' + countItems2);
  }
}
```

```css
.black, .blue { width: 25px; height:25px; display: inline-block }
.black { background-color:black }
.blue { background-color:blue }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">click me!</button>
<button id="btn2">click me!</button>
<div id="div1" style="background-color: #00f2f2;width: 1000px">
  <input id="inp" value="0"><br><br>
</div>
<p>
  <span class="countBlack"></span><br>
  <span class="countBlue"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: If you want to more, then you need to make a array with your model and check the difference everytime user action

Comment: @Alex Can you upvote my post if you find it usefull please ?